# How to show data in realtime database firebase in react js

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

[image] [image]
[image]
import React, { useState ,useEffect} from 'react';

import { Link ,useHistory,useParams} from 'react-router-dom';

import { getDatabase,ref, child, get } from 'firebase/database';

import { auth, db } from './Config/Config';

export default function User()

const [user,setUser]=useState()

const {id}=useParams();

const dbRef = ref(getDatabase());

get(child(dbRef, `AllUsers/${id}`)).then((snapshot) => {

if (snapshot.exists()) {

```
setUser(...snapshot.val());
```

} else {

console.log('user',user)
return (

{id}

```
</div>
```

)
}

Comment: i want to show these id in front end

Comment: Please describe in full the problems you are having - what is failing and why, what you have tried and why it didn't work etc. At the moment your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

IDK how to use that firebase id tho but if want to show data getting as responses then you already store firebase data in the local-state now you can use that state to get data and show anywhere {user.id} or whatever ur getting in response!

Comment: it give me value undifiend

Comment: can you show me what response you getting and what you want to show in ur ui ? you are storing response in localstate right ? just console.log (user)

Comment: yes i add a pic please  see it .I want to show data in here but in console the data comes empty

Comment: yes i write user.id but it is not show?

Comment: @Fahad Can you show what data you are getting in that user object ?

Comment: @Fahad please add code snapshot to understand !you are getting any data from api ? im not sure that user object is empty or it has same data inside it if user has data then u can use them

Answer (score 0):

It's a design pattern using lowercase as params. So rename to allusers or all-users.

Are you sure you getting the right ID from params ?
also, paste your full code pls.

Comment: sir it is a full code.Plasse give me a solution no body help me